# Store class with nested table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a class that I am using to store player stats for various seasons

```
public class PlayerModel
{
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, SeasonStats> SeasonStats { get; set; }

    public PlayerModel()
    {
        this.SeasonStats = new Dictionary<int, SeasonStats>();
        //Add season stats for each year
        this.SeasonStats.Add(2012, new SeasonStats());
        this.SeasonStats.Add(2011, new SeasonStats());
        this.SeasonStats.Add(2010, new SeasonStats());
    }
}

public class SeasonStats
{
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use Entity Framework to store the object but I am not sure what attributes to place on the SeasonStats property to have Entity store the object correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SeasonStats is a class that strictly related to Player means there can not be SeasonStats without a Player, so you must define a composition relation between them. It means you have to declare an one-to-many relation, which SeasonStats has exactly on Player, first of all you have to modify classes like this

```
public class PlayerModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Player")]
    public ICollection<SeasonStats> SeasonStats { get; set; }

    public PlayerModel()
    {
        this.SeasonStats = new List<SeasonStats>();
        //Add season stats for each year
        this.SeasonStats.Add(new SeasonStats(){Year = 2012};);
        this.SeasonStats.Add(new SeasonStats(){Year = 2011};);
        this.SeasonStats.Add(new SeasonStats(){Year = 2010};);
    }
}

public class SeasonStats
{
    [Key]
    public int Year { get; set;}
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlayerID")]
    public Player Player{get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PlayerID {get; set; }
}
```